# iMacros loop based search and extract result

Tags: imacros

I am trying to build a macro that automatically search a Keyword from a CSV file and paste it in a search box then click on search button, when search result comes up then click on that result.So far I can go maximum click on search button and bring search result but I can't do later. Now What command should I put that macro so it clicks on the search result. Please see below images

[image: please see the screenshot]

Below is the code I am using:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE Extracts.csv

SET !LOOP 2

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !Extract_TEST_POPUP NO

URL GOTO=https://reports.zoho.com/ZDBDataSheetView.cc?DBID=302139000000984683

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ZDBMainBox

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:ZDBObjSearchTxtFld CONTENT= {{!COL1}}

wait seconds = 3

TAG POS=131 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=ID:{{!COL1}}
```

Can anyone please help me to figure out the right command?

Comment: How about if you replace col1 with col0 ?

Comment: which COL1 I should replace ?  I tried to replace with last one by Col0 but not working .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX

TAB T=1

SET !DATASOURCE Extracts.csv

SET !LOOP 2

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

SET !Extract_TEST_POPUP NO

URL GOTO=https://reports.zoho.com/ZDBDataSheetView.cc?DBID=302139000000984683

TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=ID:ZDBMainBox

TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:ZDBObjSearchTxtFld CONTENT={{!COL1}}

wait seconds = 3

TAG POS=131 TYPE=DIV ATTR=TXT:

TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:*{{!COL1}}*
```

I tried this code and it worked. I replaced the ID with TXT in last line of the code.